# Why do WPF tabs become "unresponsive" when `Dispatcher.Invoke()` is called?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

[image: Unresponsive Tabs Video]

As I understand it, WPF "messages" (e.g. a button click handler) are added to an internal prioritized queue.  A single UI thread is then responsible for processing the queued messages.

Unfortunately my knowledge of WPF is not deep enough to understand the internal working of the framework. So my question is, given that there is only 1 thread processing messages...

- What is the internal sequence of events (high level) that is leading to the tabs becoming unresponsive?

### Observed Behavior

1. If you click slowly, the `TabControl` behaves as expected.

   - To reproduce: click 1 tab every 4 seconds.
   - It appears that if you give the `TabControl.SelectedIndex` data binding an opportunity to complete, the control will behave as designed.
2. If you click tabs quickly, then some of the tabs will become unresponsive.

   - To reproduce: click as many tabs as you can within 3 seconds.

### Additional Reading

- [Two selected tabs in tabcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25997785/949681)

  - While the behavior is similar, this article is different because the symptom is the result of using a `Tab` + `MessageBox`.

### Sample Code

The following code can be used to reproduce the behavior, whereby, WPF tabs become permanently selected.

Paste into `MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <WrapPanel Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock>
                1. Click on as many tabs as possible within 3 seconds.<LineBreak/>
                2. Wait until multiple tabs are selected.<LineBreak/>
                3. Uncheck the `Simulate Bug` checkbox.<LineBreak/>
            </TextBlock>
        </WrapPanel>
        <CheckBox Grid.Row="1" IsChecked="{Binding CanSimulateBug}" Content="Simulate Bug"/>
        <TabControl x:Name="ColorWorkspaces" Grid.Row="2" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTab, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <TabItem x:Name="RedTab" Header="Red"/>
            <TabItem x:Name="OrangeTab" Header="Orange"/>
            <TabItem x:Name="YellowTab" Header="Yellow"/>
            <TabItem x:Name="GreenTab" Header="Green"/>
            <TabItem x:Name="BlueTab" Header="Blue"/>
            <TabItem x:Name="VioletTab" Header="Violet"/>
        </TabControl>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding Status}"/>
    </Grid>
```

Paste into `MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int _selectedTab;
        private string _status;
        private bool _canSimulateBug;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.CanSimulateBug = true;
            this.Status = String.Empty;
            this.DataContext = this;
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public bool CanSimulateBug
        {
            get
            {
                return _canSimulateBug;
            }
            set
            {
                _canSimulateBug = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string Status
        {
            get
            {
                return _status;
            }
            set
            {
                _status = value ?? string.Empty;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public int SelectedTab
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedTab;
            }
            set
            {
                UpdateStatus($"SelectedTab changing... Value={value}");

                if (this.CanSimulateBug)
                {
                    SimulateBug(value);
                }
                _selectedTab = value;
                UpdateStatus($"SelectedTab changed. Value={value}");
                // This missing line was added as per 
Felix's comment
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private void UpdateStatus(string message)
        {
            var formattedMessage = $"[{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}] {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}: {message}";
            this.Status = formattedMessage;
            Debug.WriteLine(formattedMessage);
        }

        private void SimulateBug(int id)
        {
            var delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
            UpdateStatus($"Bug simulation started... ID={id}, Delay={delay}");

            // IMPORTANT: If you comment out this following line
            // ... the application will behave as expected.
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke( // blocking call
                DispatcherPriority.Background, // tells UI thread to execute this as lowest priority job
                new Action(delegate { /* do nothing */ }));

            Thread.Sleep(delay);
            UpdateStatus($"Bug simulation complete. ID={id}");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I was skimming the code and see `SelectedTab`'s setter doesn't have a `RaisePropertyChanged()` call.  Shouldn't it?

Comment: Because you block the UI with `Thread.Sleep(delay)` and it has nothing to do with your `Dispatcher.Invoke()` call. BTW The bug is in your code ;o)

Comment: some comments to your title: `invoke` only avoid cross access exception, not guarentee ui responsive. it's multi *threading* or *async* does that(i don't see them in your code).

Comment: @FelixCastor: why technical yes `SelectedTab` should have a call to `RaisePropertyChanged()`, it makes no difference in this example. `SelectedTab` is only changed by via the UI. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: @SirRufo: Respectfully, this is "effectively" a single threaded application. `Thread.Sleep()` is just slowing things down. If you remove `Dispatcher.Invoke()` the application behaves as expected.

Comment: @Pressacco Then you are having a different version then me. Method `SimulateBug` is called from `SelectedTab` property setter on UI Thread context and therefor that will block the UI

Comment: @LeiYang: Thank you for your feedback. I understand that `Dispatcher.Invoke()` is used to guarantee that provided delegate/callback is executed by the UI thread.  My question is not about UI responsiveness. My question is about: why does the WPF `TabControl` behavior completely change when `Dispatcher.Invoke()` is called?  Note that one of the parameters is `DispatcherPriority.Background` which is forcing the UI thread to execute all higher priority messages first.

Comment: try call `SimulateBug` like this `Task.Run(()=>{SimulateBug()})`; `Thread.Sleep` to`Task.Sleep`

Comment: Thank you @LeiYang. Changing the code to `Task.Run(() => SimulateBug(value))` and `await Task.Delay(delay);`... the application behaves as expected.  I will have to reflect on this because while this does stop the "unresponsive tab" behavior, it does not explain why the problem exists in the original sample code.

Comment: the original code is called(or run) by the UI thread, and you sleep on that thread, causing ui sleep(when you sleep you cannot receive messages, hear, or see, right?). as i said, threading(Task here) solve it.

Comment: @LeiYang: It is my believe that the mouse clicks are queued by the operating system because: if the UI thread is sleeping for 3 seconds... then how come the UI receives the clicks for the other tabs? Look at _Green_ and _Blue_ in the video above.  IMHO I think threading "solved" the problem here by avoiding a timing issue / race condition.

Comment: i think you should call `RaisePropertyChanged();` as soon as the `set` is called. currently you call it at last.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242814/discussion-between-pressacco-and-lei-yang).

Comment: When a type like `Window` extends `DispatcherObject` you must prefer dependency properties over implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`. The performance of dependency properties is significantly better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your complete code is executing on a single thread. You can't execute concurrent operations using a single thread. What you are currently doing is to block the main thread twice (too long) by invoking two potentially long-running operations synchronously:

1. Synchronous `Dispatcher` invocation using `Dispatcher.Invoke`:

```cs
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {}, DispatcherPriority.Background);
```

2. Synchronous thread sleep:

```cs
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
```

While executing these synchronous operations, the main thread is not free to execute the logic (which is in this case part of the `Selector`, which is a superclass of `TabControl`) that manages the selection state of the hosted items.
The main thread is blocked by waiting for the `Dispatcher` to return and then by sending it to sleep i.e. suspending it.
As a result the `Selector` is not able to unselect the previously selected `TabItem`.
The `Selector` is able to cancel the selection procedure, which involves handling the selected item and unselecting every other item (in case multi-select is not supported). Obviously, the `Selector` cancels the unselection/processing of the pending items.
You should be able to test this by listening to the `Selector.Unselected` event which you attach to the `TabItem`. It should not be raised. Apparently the blocking of the main thread creates a race condition for the internal item validation of the `Selector`.
To fix this race condition it should be sufficient to increase the `DispatcherPriority` of the queued dispatcher messages to at least `DispatcherPriority.DataBind` (above `DispatcherPriority.Input`):

```cs
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {}, DispatcherPriority.DataBind);
```

This is not the recommended fix, although it fixes the race condition and therefore the issue of multiple selected tabs as the critical code can now execute in time. The real underlying problem is the blocked main thread (which actually is a blocked `Dispatcher`).

You never want to block the main thread. Now you understand why.
For this reason .NET introduced the TPL. Additionally, the compiler/runtime environment allows true asynchronous execution: by delegating execution to the OS, .NET can use kernel level features like interrupts. This way .NET can allow the main thread to continue e.g., to process essential UI related events like device input.

Part of the interface between OS level and framework level is the `Dispatcher` and the `InputManager`. The `Dispatcher` basically manages the associated thread. In an STA application this is the main thread. Now, when you block the main thread using `Thread.Sleep`, the `Dispatcher` can't continue to work on the message queue that contains handlers that are executed on the associated dispatcher thread (main thread).
The `Dispatcher` is now unable to execute the input events posted by the `InputManager`. Since the dependency property system (on which routed events and the data binding engine is based on) and usually the code of UI controls are also executed on the `Dispatcher`, they are also suspended.

The combination of the very low dispatcher priority `DispatcherPriority.Background` in conjunction with the long `Thread.Sleep` makes the problem even worse.

---

The solution is to not block the main thread:

1. Post work to the `Dispatcher` asynchronously and allow the application to continue while the job is enqueued and pending by calling `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync`:

```cs
Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => {}, DispatcherPriority.Background);
```

2. Execute blocking I/O bound operations asynchronously using `async`/`await`:

```cs
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
```

3. Execute blocking CPU bound operations concurrently:

```cs
Task.Run(() => {});
```

Your fixed code would look as followed:

```cs
private async Task SimulateNoBugAsync(int id)
{
  var delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
  UpdateStatus($"Bug simulation started... ID={id}, Delay={delay}");

  // If you need to wait for a result or for completion in general,
  // await the Dispatcher.InvokeAsync call.
  Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => {}, DispatcherPriority.Background);
  await Task.Delay(delay);

  UpdateStatus($"Bug simulation complete. ID={id}");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed post.  Your effort is much appreciated.  To clarify: I did not write this code, and my personal coding style is always avoid blocking the UI thread.  That said, a client has asked me to look into this behavior & I thought this was an interesting case because: (1) the sample code is **not** trying to execute concurrent operations and (2) I understand that UI messages are consumed by a single thread.  What is interesting here is that even if the UI thread was blocked for 5 minutes once it resumes, it should just continue executing queued messages.

Comment: Although I have been unable to prove this, I suspect the observed behavior is related to: (1) user clicks on first tab (2) `TabControl` queues several messages `Render`, `Databinding`, etc. (3) when the data binding message is executed `SelectedTab` property is called (4) which in-turn `Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, Action)` forces the UI's prioritized message queue to be cleared. My hypothesis is that Step#4 is causing the UI messages to be executed in an unexpected order thus leaving the `Tab` in a weird state.  Remove `Dispatcher.Invoke()` blocking call & code works fine

Comment: You are right that the `Dispatcher` continues to execute the queued handlers as soon resources allow this. Your observed issue is subject to the implementation details of the `TabControl` (or the superclass `Selector` to be more precise). I have edited the answer to add more information.

Comment: Basically, the `Selector` is able to cancel the selection process of its managed/hosted items. This process involves select and unselect. By blocking the `Dispatcher` you create a race condition for the logic of the `Selector` which leads to cancellation of the unselection of the items. You can improve this behavior by increasing the `DispatcherPriority` to `DataBind` or higher (it must be above `Input` for sure).

Comment: Regarding your rendered scenario: note that  (4) does not force the message queue to be cleared. Dispatcher.Invokes basically inserts a new message into the queue. The continuation, the code after the Dispatcher.Invoke is also executed on the Dispatcher (main thread). The Dispatcher will continue to empty the queued messages after the current method has returned. But sadly, this is not happening as Thread.Sleep is suspending the Dispatcher.

Comment: Removing the `Dispatcher.Invoke` only *appears* to solve the problem. It only reduces the time the `Dispatcher` is blocked enough to eliminate the race condition. It's still a blocked Dispatcher which can lead to more side effects if the complexity of the application or the enqueued delegate increases. You can alternatively increase the `DispatcherPriority` or reduce the `Thread.Sleep` duration. The point is that the too low `DispatcherPriority.Background` together with a `Thread.Sleep` is too much. The real solution is to not block the Dispatcher. It must be able to process its queue.

Comment: *"What is interesting here is that even if the UI thread was blocked for 5 minutes once it resumes, it should just continue executing queued messages"* - Not necessarily. If the enqueued delegate comes from a background thread or a thread that is not associated with this Dispatcher in general, then the enqueued job could be cancelled due to e.g., a time out. The enqueuing thread can call `DispatcherOperation.Abort` at any time. This is another scenario where blocking the Dispatcher can introduce unpredictable behavior due to another race condition.